# Prompt users to save when there are input on textboxes when leaving the page asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, save

I found several solutions to this using jquery and javascript, however, it has to declare all the fields in jquery, but its not efficient since I have 30+ asp textboxes on my form, how can i prompt the user to save the data or changes have been made on page unload.

Comment: _"it has to declare all the fields in jquery, but its not efficient since I have 30+ asp textboxes on my form"_ - You make it sound like you're doing them all individually. Can't you use a single selector that just takes all the inputs in your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

Be sure to set the default="" attribute on your fields!

```
function formIsDirty(form) {
    var i, j, element, type;
    if(typeof form === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i += 1) {
        element = form.elements[i];
        type = element.type;
        if (type === "checkbox" || type === "radio") {
            if (element.checked !== element.defaultChecked) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (type === "hidden" || type === "password" || type === "text" || type === "textarea") {
            if (element.value !== element.defaultValue) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (type === "select-one" || type === "select-multiple") {
            for (j = 0; j < element.options.length; j += 1) {
                if (element.options[j].selected !== element.options[j].defaultSelected) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$( window ).unload(function() {
    if(formIsDirty(document.forms["formName"])) {
        return confirm("There are unsaved changes, leave this page?");
    }
}
```

As an extra tip, when you generate the page in asp, if you set the default="" attribute to the current value in the database, you can detect not only if it's empty, but if the value has been changed.

This also allows proper use of the form.reset() button/method ([w3Schools page here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

Comment: what do you mean by attributes

Comment: <a href="something"> text </a> -- the href="" bit is the attrbute, it's a property="value" pair within a html <tag>

Comment: .. so in this case <input type="text" default="hello" value="hello" />

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all text text boxes have the same style class ('inputField' is used below) you can use something like:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  if ($('.inputField').is(':empty')){
    alert('Please fill all text boxes');
  }
});
```